# Searching in a hash table HELP!

Tags: c++, search, hash, g++

I am trying to write a hash table for class and I can't seem to get this while loop working.  Do you guys see anything wrong with it? The while loop is ending prematurely, I think there is something wrong with my while loop condition?

```
void search(store t[], string s, int num, int table_size)
{
  int temp = num;
  bool exit = false;
  while(t[temp].data != s && !exit){
    temp++;
    if (temp == table_size){
      cout<<"reached 0 inside while loop"<<endl;
        temp = 0;
    }
    if (temp == num){
      cout<<"test search loop"<<endl;          //I can't seem to get into here.
      exit = true;
    }
  }
  if(t[num].data == s)
    cout<<"("<<s<<")"<<" appears "<<t[num].count<<" times."<<endl;
  else
    cout<<"your string is not in my table"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Please give an example of usage. How are you calling this function? What values are you passing for num, table_size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop seems ok,

but are you sure about the following line ?

```
if(t[num].data == s)
    cout<<"("<<s<<")"<<" appears "<<t[num].count<<" times."<<endl;
```

shouldn't be the following instead ?

```
if(t[temp].data == s)
    cout<<"("<<s<<")"<<" appears "<<t[temp].count<<" times."<<endl;
```

Because obviously you are running the whole table until the cycle is complete or until you find the good one [ ie: while( *t[temp].data != s* ...) ]. So I guess that you are searching for the good *temp* index but you don't use it after you while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
 int temp = num;
```

to

```
 int temp = 0;
```